# How to make dynamic name selectors (infinitely)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not familiar with jQuery and i have redundant jQuery calls, I would like to put them in a loop.

```
$('.class1').on('click', function () { ...
$('.class2').on('click', function () { ...
$('.class3').on('click', function () { ...
$('.class4').on('click', function () { ...
$('.class5').on('click', function () { ...
...
```

This is one of complete call :

```
$('.class1').on('click', function () { 
     if ($('.anotherclass1').is(':visible')) { 
         $(this).text("Show"); $('.anotherclass1').hide(); 
     } else { 
         $(this).text("Hide"); $('.anotherclass1').show(); 
     } 
});
```

Is there a way to do this without the repetition?

Here my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vj3wagt/)

Comment: if you can give us html that would be awesome...

Comment: It would be better to have a single class that you apply to all of the elements, then add a `data-` attribute to the HTML and use that to match inside of the handler...

Comment: I updated your title and question to closer match [ask]. Feel free to roll back if it is not to your liking.

Comment: Ok, I'll be more careful now...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9vj3wagt/1/ Added below to demonstrate with your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your items just have the same class `someclass` and a data attribute like `data-target="#someotherid"`:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9vj3wagt/1/

```
$('.someclass').on('click', function () { 
     var selector = $(this).data("target");
     $(selector).toggle();
});
```

This will use the selector in the attribute to decide which other element to toggle (which does `hide`/`show` based on visibility).

Comment: Thanks, but apparently not *popular* like `jAndy`! :)

Comment: must be the shirt :-P

Answer (score 3):

You **could** use the *starts with* operator on attributes, if you are sure that these elements only have exactly one class name. I would hate to use that in practice since there are a ton of better solutions.

```
$('[class^=class]').on('click' ...
```

Better solutions would require to see your actual HTML structure.

Since some nitbit**es :-) complained about the completeness on this answer, your full code would now look like so:

```
$('[class^=class]').on('click', function() {
    $('.another' + this.className).toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9vj3wagt/2/

Comment: Two upvotes? You got a fan club or something? This only answers a small part of the question :)

Comment: Lol, thank you for taking time to answer me. Your solution also works.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I was more after answering the querying process, but I completed the answer. It also has zero impact on the original HTML code.

Comment: the original example was not a very good example of how to do such things, but thanks for taking the time to complete your answer :)